# R packages lavaan and MeMoBootR don’t converge

Tags: predictor, mediation, lavaan

**Does anybody have experience running mediation analyses with both lavaan and MeMoBootR, and can explain why the results of each (indirect effects) might not converge with the same outcome and predictors?**Lavaan returns a significant indirect effect (B = 0.000313*, CI [0.00, 0.00], p = .0417) and the MeMoBootR package returns a non-significant result (B = 0.000230*, Sobel: p = .1016, CI[-0.0001, 0.0005]. Also, the proportion of the mediation effect is 28% (MeMoBoot) vs.70% (lavaan).

**This is the code I used with MeMoBootR:**

```
saved = mediation1(y = "FEMOTION", # DV
                  x = "Mean_MVPA_age7", # IV
                  m = "TC1", # mediator
                  cvs = c("binary_ethnicity", "IMD_ewsni_age7", "DDKESSLER", "Pub_both"), # any covariates
                  df = na.omit(df_boys), # dataframe
                  with_out = T, # logical value: want to keep the outliers in model TRUE or exclude them from the model FALSE
                  nboot = 10000, # number of bootstraps (for indirect effect)
                  conf_level = .95 # CI width
                  )
```

**This is the code I used with lavaan:**

```
# MODEL 1: PA - CGT (here TC1 only) - EmoSDQ
# MODEL WITH TC1 as potential mediator
# Define the model
#general: my_mod <- 'outcome ~ c*predictor + b*mediator
                  #mediator ~ a*predictor'   

Depression_mod <- 'FEMOTION ~ c*(Mean_MVPA_age7 + binary_ethnicity + IMD_ewsni_age7 + DDKESSLER + Pub_both) + b*TC1
                  TC1 ~ a*(Mean_MVPA_age7 + binary_ethnicity + IMD_ewsni_age7 + DDKESSLER + Pub_both)
                  
                  indirect_effect := a*b
                  total_effect := c + (a*b)
                  '
```

```
# fit the model to the data using the sem() function with FIML and robust SEs
Depression_fit <- lavaan::sem(Depression_mod, data = df_boys, missing = "FIML", estimator = "MLR") 

# apply the broom::glance() function to the fitted model to view the fit statistics and apply broom::tidy() to it to view the model parameters
#summarize the model
broom::glance(Depression_fit)
broom::tidy(Depression_fit, conf.int = TRUE)
```

**Did I add the confounders correctly into the model here?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I only know about lavaan. Start with a simple model, and build up slowly from there. Add one variable at a time, and you might find the problem.

Comment: You didn't provide your `lavaan()` call, only the model syntax.  If `mediation1()` returns an object of `class()` lavaan, then you can compare the `parTable()` output to see how the fitted models differ,